# iOS 8 PHP file upload error (server file size = 0)

Tags: php, ios, iphone, file-upload, ios8

I have 2 webapps [iEmpty](http://iempty.tooliphone.net) & [iCustom](http://icustom.tooliphone.net). Both ask the users to upload some image files from their iPhone/iPad.

I have some **iOS8 (beta) users** that tells me that "it doesn't works with iOS8".

For these iOS users, I made logs to see in details my uploaded file (through a classic HTML file upload field). 
It appears that there is **no error, but file size is zero** !

If I dump the $_FILES['myfilefieldname'] in the logs I have somrthing like this :

```
array (  
    'name' => 'image.jpg',
    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpaCGkNg',
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => 0,
)
```

I have **no problems with iOS7** or Chrome desktop browser simulating the iOS8 user agent string...

The problem is that **I don't have iOS8**, so it is difficult for me to debug and find what the problem is !

- Can anyone already has the same problem ?
- Can you please test with iOS8 and tell me if you have the problem ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Perhaps it's time to *get* iOS8 then.

Comment: @marko : I can't as I don't have an Apple dev ID and my devices are not compatible with iOS8... that's why I ask for help here !

Comment: The cost of doing iOS app development is a representative set of devices with which to test - and an active ADC developer program subscription.  You cannot escape this.   Had you got the ADC membership, you could at least get the iOS8 simulator

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old, but I ran into this problem and it took me two weeks to find that I had a problem in the file path that I was trying to upload (it is stored in the Documents directory before upload) :

[Refer Technical Note 2406 by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2406/_index.html)

The breaking change is

> Beginning in iOS 8, the Documents and Library directories are no longer siblings of your application's bundle.

Don't store full path/URL to your documents. Store the file name and always generate full path/URL with recommended approach.